# Removing up button just from Home activity

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to delete the up button just from the home activity?
i want it to stay in the other fragments but just not the home.
Thanks

Comment: by default it is not visible. Is it? Did you use custom toolbar as supportAction bar?

Comment: in my case it's visible . yes

Answer (score 0):

Add a single toolbar in all the fragment

...

Abstract the toolbar.xml

...

(From fragment)

View view= Inflater(...);

view.getContext().setSupportActionBar("toolbar");

getActionBar().setHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Do this after you set toolbar as supportActionBar

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: thank you , but this deletes the up navigation from all the other fragments too